# If $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}+\cdots+\frac{k}{x_n^{k}}$, find $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu\neq0$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n^\lambda=\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given sequence $\{x_n\}$ satisfies $x_1>0$, and there exists integer $k\geq3$ such that$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{2}{x_n^2}+\cdots+\frac{k}{x_n^{k}},$$find $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mu\neq0$ such that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nx_n^\lambda=\mu.$$
I think $x_n^\lambda$ must approach to zero when $n$ approachs to $\infty$ if$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nx_n^\lambda$ exists. As $x_n$ is an increasing sequence and $x_1>0$, I guess that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$ and $\lambda<0$. However, I don't know how to prove that. What's more, I think that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nx_n^\lambda=\mu \neq 0$ implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^{-\lambda}}{n}$ exists. The first thing that occurs to me is to apply the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem:$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^{-\lambda}}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}^{-\lambda}-x_n^{-\lambda}.$$
However, I don't know what to do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture about $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=+\infty$ is correct. We know that $\{x_n\}$ is increasing and positive. If $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=A\in(0,\infty)$. Letting $n\to\infty$ in both sides of
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{2}{x_n^2}+\cdots+\frac{k}{x_n^{k}}\tag{$*$}$$
gives that
$$A=A+\frac1A+\cdots+\frac k{A^k},$$
which is a contradiction. Hence $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=+\infty$.

Squaring both sides of $(*)$ gives that
$$x_{n+1}^2=x_n^2+2+y_n,$$
where $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$. Now, [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) implies that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2}n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({x_{n+1}^2}-{x_{n}^2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({x_n^2+2+y_n}-{x_{n}^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2+y_n^2)=2.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n^{-2}=\frac12.$$